# 新しい古いうち.　What does this mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

There's new, old and home?? in it. But I've seen multiple translations. If anyone could help it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the context? Where did you see it?

Comment: Its in a table of contents in a Totoro book 1.新しい古いうち

Comment: Ohh I see... Yeah I remember that.

Answer (score 15):

> 新しい古いうち

This is from 「となりのトトロ」. サツキ, メイ and their father move into a very old house. So the house is *new* to them (新しい[家]{うち}, new place, new home), though the house/building itself is actually very old. Literally "Our new old house". So I think it means "Our new home in an old house" or "An old house we newly moved in".

Comment: i think it should be translated "new old house" without the comma to capture this meaning. "new, old house" feeling a bit contradictory

Comment: It's similar to the dilemma of what you call your newly purchased used car.

Comment: @mackygoo, A.Ellett ありがとうございます！ ＾＾

Comment: ああ、コンマがあると「新しくて古いうち」、コンマがないと「新しい古いうち」になるんですね…

Comment: EDIT: Oh I see, it means *an old house we newly moved into*.

Comment: @naruto  Yes.  In English the comma (in this case) and a semicolon can often act like the word "and".

Answer (score 0):

> 新しい古いうち

It might be written as 新しい古い家{うち}.
If my guess is correct, it must be "古｛ふる｝い建築｛けんちく｝様式｛ようしき｝の新築｛しんちく｝の家｛いえ｝ *a house of a newly built old architectural style*".

---

### EDIT:

I admit it was my perfect defeat as Chocolate knew of "となりのトトロ" from which the OP cited "新しい古いうち".
I accept that the voting results is not positive because of my complete defeat. I do not regret it either. However, I am worried about how this minus evaluation appears on serious people who are studying Japanese. The reason why I prepared this EDIT is to prevent them from misunderstanding that my answer is essentially incorrect and that Chocolate's answer is correct. The correctness of the answer is only whether the answerers knew the unfamiliar or rather strange expression in "となりのトトロ" or not.

By the way, apart from the author and the readers who know the scene of "となりのトトロ", most of the Japanese who hear "新しい古いうち" should think at first as "what?" When I first saw this strange phrase I thought I have to interpret it and answer OP the question somehow. I examined it very hard. And after making a striving effort I could just reach to the idea of a newly build noted Japanese farmhouse with steeply slanted thatched-roofs in *Gassho-zukuri* style, that I showed in the picture.

To OP, first of all, please be aware that "新しい古いうち" does not make sense normally or sounds strange in Japanese. You can use it without problems if you say like "新しく**移{うつ}った**古いうち" or "新しく**引｛ひ｝っ越｛こ｝してきた**古いうち". Also, it is necessary for "a newly purchased used car" written in Pawl Rowe's comment to say as "新しく**買｛か｝った**古い車｛くるま｝" as opposed to "新しい古い車".

By the way if you can say "新しい古いうち" for "the old house you newly moved into" you can say "古い古いうち" for "the old house you moved out of".

There is an expression "古くて新しい" similar to that of "新しい古い something" useful when OP learns it.
I understand that this is an adjective phrase with a positive meaning used in nuances like being re-evaluated in this modern society highly in the value of the traditional old one or being rather novel, wonderful or useful of things that have existed from long ago compared to current novelty things.

Example:

- [**古くて新しい**成功の必須要件「グリット」とは何か](http://business.nikkeibp.co.jp/atcl/opinion/16/112800029/)
  *What is "grit" that is said an old but new essential requirement of success?*
- [**古くて新しい**！ VRダンジョンクローラー『KryptCrawler』トレイラー](https://www.gamespark.jp/article/2017/07/19/74682.html)
  *This work is "old but new" because it combines traditional turn-based game play with real-time battle and trap avoidance. VR function provides unparalleled dungeon experience.*
  [KryptCrawler](https://bigbossbattle.com/kryptcrawler-vr-dungeon-crawler-out-now-release-trailer-within/), VR Dungeon Crawler, Out Now; Release Trailer Within
- [**古くて新しい**「ネットワーク分離」が“要注目技術”に返り咲いた理由](http://techtarget.itmedia.co.jp/tt/news/1606/16/news04.html)
  *The reason why old and new "network separation technology that separates the Internet from LAN" has come back as "attention-requiring technology"*

#### 日本語

「新しい古いうち」をＯＰが引用した出典である「となりのトトロ」を、Chocolateさんもご存知のようでしたので私の完敗です。

完敗して評価がプラスでないのは認めます。また悔しくもありません。しかし、このマイナス評価が、日本語を勉強しているまじめな人にどう映るのかが心配です。私がこのEDITを用意した理由は、偏に、日本語を勉強している人が私の回答が本質的に間違っており、Chocolateさんの回答があっていると誤解することを防ぐためです。回答の正誤は単に「となりのトトロ」の表現を知っていたかどうかだけです。

ところで、「となりのトトロ」の作者と情景が分かる読者は別にして、「新しい古いうち」を聞いた日本人の大部分は、たぶん私と同じく「？」と最初は考えるはずです。この奇妙なフレーズを解釈してなんとかＯＰに回答してあげようと私は一所懸命考えました。調べました。そして、合掌造りの建物にたどりついただけでも努力賞（?）ものです。

ＯＰさんへ。「新しい古いうち」は、普通には通用しない日本語であることをまず知ってください。「新しく**移った**古いうち」や「新しく**引っ越してきた**古いうち」なら問題なく使えます。
また、Pawl Roweさんのコメントにある newly purchased used car も、「新しい古い車」ではなく「新しく**買った**古い車」のように言う必要があります。

ところで、これがトトロで使われているのなら、「前のうち」は「古い古いうち」と言うこともできますね。トトロの作家さん、おもしろいですね。

これからは真面目な話ですが、ＯＰが覚えてよい類似の表現に「古くて新しい」というものがあります。これは、この現代社会で伝統ある古いものの価値が見直される、あるいは、出尽くした感のある新規のものに比べて前からあるものがかえって斬新である。あるいは役に立つ。すばらしいというようなニュアンスで用いられる肯定的な形容詞だと理解しております。手許の辞書で見つからないので、自分なりに解釈しているものを書いておりますが、いい言葉だと思っております。「古くて新しい」をうまく説明したものがあればご紹介ください。また、私の解釈が間違っておれば訂正します。

[image]

Comment: 個人的にはそんな長文で語るほどの心配はないと思いますよー。文法や語彙的にはこれ以上ないくらいに平易ですし、英語でも"The new old ～"みたいな言い方は別に珍しくありません。「文脈がないと突飛で曖昧に見える、そういうよくある表現技法の一種だよ」の一言で十分かなーと。（ちなみに分類としては[オクシモロン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%92%9E%E7%9D%80%E8%AA%9E%E6%B3%95)です）